# Why can't I install this module?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to improve the quality of photos and found [neural-enhance](https://github.com/alexjc/neural-enhance) on GitHub. There was a problem with the library.

```
root/test/*.jpg Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "enhance.py", line 583, in <module>
    img = scipy.ndimage.imread(filename, mode='RGB')
AttributeError: module 'scipy.ndimage' has no attribute 'imread'
```

Comment: What version of scipy do you have installed? Per [these docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.1.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.imread.html), `scipy.ndimage.imread` was removed in version 1.2.0 which was quite some time ago.

Answer (score 0):

As [this link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.1.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.imread.html) says, this function removed from version `1.2.0`. try to use `imageio.imread` instead.

```
import imageio
img = imageio.imread(filename, pilmode ='RGB')
```